# SSIS Sending Email with a Link

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, ssis

I have a couple of SSIS questions regarding the Send Mail task. The first is if I am pulling my email body and subject directly from a SQL server table and putting it into a variable, is there a way in the expression builder for the MessageSource to replace certain values (such as a flag like !!!) with other variable values?

Second, is there a way that when you pull an email body from SQL into a variable to have a link in that email? I have tried to `<a href>` tag it in the SQL table and the code comes through in every email that I have tried. This is also using Expression builder like mentioned above. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SSIS variables to construct your message using Expression Task.

The Send Mail Task only supports plaintext.  [Sending an HTML Mail Message with the Script Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is one alternative, [CozyRoc Send Mail Task Plus](http://cozyroc.com/ssis/send-mail-task) is another.

Comment: I ended up using the script task. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, yes, just use replace function in the expression builder.

For question 2, I assume you should have access to msdb? If so calling [msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms190307.aspx) stored procedure to send a html email with link embedded.

Comment: I don't have the role necessary and will not get the role.

Comment: I assume the package will be executed in SQL Agent? If so as long as the service account has permission to execute sp_send_dbmail, the html email can be sent. If the service account cannot access the sp, or the package is running outside of the scope, then you probably need to look at 3rd party component, or just use script task to send the html style mail.